# Unity top bar 100% transparent

Tags: unity, 14.04, transparency

Just wondering if anyone knows how to get unity's top bar to be 100% transparent. I have it so on my second screen, but it seems to add a bit of a background on my main screen. See the screenshot below for what i'm talking about.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: 'Unity Tweak' might help you...

Comment: the app link https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/

Comment: You can try in ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager) > Ubuntu Unity Plugin > General > Background Color setting Opacity to 2. That may help as currently there is a bug where that opacity affects the panel. (the setting of 0 in Background Color > opacity will not produce transparent nor will obviously any high value

Comment: Hmm no luck... pretty much the same appearance. Might this be a bug or possibly design of unity? To keep the panel from looking odd in combination with the launcher?

Answer (score 2):

Install CompizConfig Setting Manager from Ubuntu Software Center or through `apt-get`.
In CompizConfig, under the category "Desktop", go to "UBUNTU UNITY PLUGIN".
In that, under "General", you will find "Panel Opacity".
In that you can select Opacity varying from 1.0000 to 0.0000....
And to properly get result you may log out or restart your device..

Comment: There is only one mistake in your answer. Varying opacity from 1.0000 to 0.0000. Not from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mani suggested. Install Unity-Tweak-Tool. That will install a tool for costumizing the Unity interface. Somewhere in the settings, there should be a bar transparency setting.

Comment: I'm familiar with unity tweak, and have set Panel Opacity to 0.00, yet I still get the semi-transparency on my main screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In unity tweak tool panel I set to max transparency and in CCSM I also have Opacity 0.0000 and panel is still not fully transparent.

However I found solution here:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/transparent-panel-titlebar-ubuntu-unity/

In CCSM aside panel opacity also background opacity must be set to 1 and not 0. To do that I had to set it first on maximum and then to 1 (otherwise it didn't want to save 1...).

Answer (score 0):

Download  unity tweak tool from ubuntu Software centre.
Launch this app.
Under unity open panel and maximise transparency level.
Then again under unity open Search And set Background blur to off.
And that's all.